# Email Template : Dark Mode

Tags: html-email

can any one has zero to 100 Idea about how dark mode works in email development and do`s and dont`s of with any sample template.

I used this media query but seems not that much supportive.

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark) {
        .darkmode {
            background: #000;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need a bit more than that, but not much works with Gmail. This will work with Apple, for example, and a couple of others. But Apple is easily 50% market share of many email lists, so, it's a good start.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for Heads up.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of what you can do with codes condensed from Litmus blog.

```css
:root {
    color-scheme: light dark;
    supported-color-schemes: light dark;
  }


@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark) {
        .darkmode {
            background: #000000;
        }
        [data-ogsc] .darkmode { background-color: #000000 !important; }
        [data-ogsb] .darkmode { background-color: #000000 !important; }
    }
```

```html
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">

<div class="darkmode" style="background-color:#ff0000;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Source: [Litmus blog](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/)

Comment: I think the [data-ogsc] lines are meant to be outside the @media query, see: https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/

Comment: @MiguelStevens if its outside the media query, It will target the class regardless of dark/light mode. Get your hands on this and see if its different to what I have above. [Get this package](https://www.litmus.com/resources/subscriber-love-email-templates/)

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Thanks @syfer

Comment: @MiguelStevens anytime. its good to ask and test always.

Answer (score 1):

Dark mode media queries seem to only work for very few email clients. iPhone and Apple mail. I don't think there is a solution for all email clients. [data-ogsb]/[data-ogsc] attributes may work for Outlook.com/Outlook Apps but not for other email clients either.

Answer (score 0):

The dark mode is implemented differently in different email clients, some have the partial inversion dark mode implementation and some have full dark mode inversion implementation.

For your answer quickly, anywhere you need to use dark mode for background colors you can use

```
background-image:linear-gradient(colorOfYourChoice,colorOfYourChoice);
```

This works because the general method of implementation of dark mode inverts the color in the css when its rendered, but if you use linear gradient that wont happen, and your chosen color would stay.

Also, the prefers-color-scheme:dark doesn't work in Gmail clients. You can use https://www.caniemail.com/ website to check which all features are supported in which all browsers.